# React array.map not rendering full length of components, only rendering one item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am creating an Ultimate Tic Tac Toe game (tic tac toe inside each square of a normal 3x3 tic tac toe game). I have a singular board component that maps each individual cell to its location on the small board and then a full board component that maps each board to its location on the large board. I have tested the `Board` component on its own and it works but the `FullBoard` component doesn't map all of the values passed in.

Board component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Cell from './Cell'

const Board = ({key, cells, onClick}) => {
  return (
    <div className="main-cells" key={key}>
        {cells.map((cell, i) => {
          return (<Cell key={i} value={cell} onClick={() => onClick(i)} />)
        })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Board
```

Fullboard component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Board from './Board'

const FullBoard = ({ boards, onClick }) => {

  return (
    <div className="board-container">
      {console.log(boards)}
      {boards.map((board, i) => {
        console.log(board[i])
        return (<Board key={i} cells={board[i]} onClick={() => onClick(i)} />)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default FullBoard
```

To my understanding these components should essentially work the same. `boards` being passed into `FullBoard` is an array of arrays, length 9. Each array is also a length 9 array of null values that will later render X's or O's

Comment: What is `board[i]` being printed as in the console?

Comment: <Board key={i} cells={board[i]} onClick={() => onClick(i)} /> try passing cells={board} instead of cells={board[i]} and think  passing  key={key} is not needed in Board component

Comment: @Azzy when I pass cells={board} it still only prints one game board but it does render all of the internal cells when before it didn't. But still unable to render all nine game boards that are passed into the map function

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by adding accessible `datakey` attributes onto the `divs` of each Board and Cell component. Also changing Board's `onCLick` function to `onClick={onClick}` instead of `onClick={() => onClick(i)}` allowed me to access the parent node of each individual cell

Board Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Cell from './Cell'

const Board = ({dataKey, cells, onClick}) => {
  return (
    <div className="main-cells" data-key={dataKey}>
      {cells.map((cell, i) => {
        return (<Cell key={i} dataKey={i} value={cell} onClick={onClick} />)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Board
```

Cell Component:

```
import React from 'react'

import './game.css'

const Cell = ({dataKey, value, onClick}) => {
  const style = value ? `inner-cells ${value}` : 'inner-cells'

  return (
    <div data-key={dataKey} className={style} onClick={onClick}>
      {value}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cell
```

FullBoard Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Board from './Board'

const FullBoard = ({ boards, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="board-container">
      {boards.map((board, i) => {
        return (<Board key ={i} dataKey={i} cells={board} onClick={onClick} />)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default FullBoard
```